# Azure StorageClient connection management

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage

Can someone share the details of the connection management used by the Azure StorageClient library?

Specifically, we are interested in:
 1) Is keep-alive being used on blob connections
 2) What is the keep alive, and lease timeouts?
 3) Is pipelining being used?

Secondarily, what are the recommendations for these settings if using the REST API directly against blob storage?

Best,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the Storage Client Library can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/microsoft-azure-api).

You can get an intimate understanding of how the library works by reading through the source code. Even better, if you find that something could be achieved to help the performance or reliability to the libraries you can modify the code and submit a pull request for review.